# Can not import libxml2 and libxslt in Python 2.7 and CentOS 7

Tags: python-2.7, libxml2, centos7, libxslt

**Can not import `libxml2` and `libxslt` in `Python 2.7` and `CentOS 7`.**

But system says that these packages are installed:

```
Package libxml2-2.9.1-5.el7_1.2.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package libxml2-devel-2.9.1-5.el7_1.2.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package libxslt-1.1.28-5.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package libxslt-devel-1.1.28-5.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
```

But can not import in Python2.7

```
Python 2.7.5 (default, Jun 24 2015, 00:41:19) 
[GCC 4.8.3 20140911 (Red Hat 4.8.3-9)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import libxml2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named libxml2
>>> import libxslt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named libxslt
>>>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

libxml2 install step

```
yum groupinstall "Development Tools"

yum  install python-devel.x86_64

rpmbuild -ba /usr/src/redhat/SPECS/libxml2.spec (this might not be required.)

##go to  RPMS/x86_64/

rpm -Uvh libxml2-python-2.7.8-1.x86_64.rpm --nodeps
```

===================================================================

libxslt install step

```
wget  http://xmlsoft.org/sources/libxslt-1.1.28.tar.gz

cd libxslt-1.1.28

./configure --with-python=/usr/bin/python2.7

make

make install
```

========================================

Comment: I don't understand. Please explain.

Comment: How to do thant in windows please ?..